# Not able to handle "/__auth/handler/" route in the url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-platform

I am requesting for authorization using the google OAuth2.0 and i have mentioned a *redirect_uri* in the google credentials screen , so the `access token code` is sent to that *redirect_uri* from google server. But when i request the origin uri , it surely redirects me to the 
`https://<my-redirect-uri>.com/__auth/handler?code=xxxxxxxx&scope=xxxxx`
but that route is not being able to handle by my express application.It's not even entering that route "__/auth/handler" ?

the origin uri is a firebase domain site , the redirect_uri is also a firebase domain site.

```
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log("////");
  res.redirect(301, "/phoneskill/log");
});

router.get("/phoneskill/log", (req, res) => {
  console.log("//phone/skill");
  fs.readFile("credentials.json", (err, content) => {
    if (err) return console.log("Error loading client secret file:", err);
    apiCaller.authorize(
      JSON.parse(content),
      res
    );
    return 1;
  });
});

router.get("/__/auth/handler", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req,"////");
  res.send("hahahhah");
});
```

```
function authorize(credentials, res) {
  const { client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = credentials;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    client_id,
    client_secret,
    redirect_uris[0]
  );

  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback, res);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, res) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: "offline",
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  res.redirect(authUrl);
}
```

The /__auth/handler should be called but its not calling.
What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: did you try to move your `__/auth/handler` to above your root router? as far as I remember specific routes should be always before the general ones...othewise the root always going to be called, ignoring the next ones

Comment: @ElmerDantas lemme check  that one

Comment: @ElmerDantas nope , didnt work

Comment: so...it might be because you're asking your server to handle a firebase callback....your server does not really have access to `__/auth/handler`...to your server get this request, you should change redirect uri to point to your domain. e.g `localhost:8080/auth/handler`...then you should see what you want

Comment: @ElmerDantas actuallly that's why i am req from www.something.firebase.com and the redireect uri  is also www.something.firebase.com and i am logging that in googlwe cloud platform

Comment: [check here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin) section => `Customizing the redirect domain for Google sign-in` and see how to work with custom domain to handle authentication

Comment: @ElmerDantas ahh i think this might work , thanks i will try it out tommorow because my request quota in Google cloud has excedded. Thankyou elmer